# How to delete 2 table rows with WHERE clause in one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my 2 tables. I would like to delete all rows with trace_id in both tables(`zipkin_annotations`, `zipkin_spans`) which are older than 5 days

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zipkin_spans (
  `trace_id_high` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'If non zero, this means the trace uses 128 bit traceIds instead of 64 bit',
  `trace_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` BIGINT,
  `debug` BIT(1),
  `start_ts` BIGINT COMMENT 'Span.timestamp(): epoch micros used for endTs query and to implement TTL',
  `duration` BIGINT COMMENT 'Span.duration(): micros used for minDuration and maxDuration query'
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE zipkin_spans ADD UNIQUE KEY(`trace_id_high`, `trace_id`, `id`) COMMENT 'ignore insert on duplicate';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zipkin_annotations (
  `trace_id_high` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'If non zero, this means the trace uses 128 bit traceIds instead of 64 bit',
  `trace_id` BIGINT NOT NULL COMMENT 'coincides with zipkin_spans.trace_id',
  `span_id` BIGINT NOT NULL COMMENT 'coincides with zipkin_spans.id',
  `a_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'BinaryAnnotation.key or Annotation.value if type == -1',
  `a_value` BLOB COMMENT 'BinaryAnnotation.value(), which must be smaller than 64KB',
  `a_type` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'BinaryAnnotation.type() or -1 if Annotation',
  `a_timestamp` BIGINT COMMENT 'Used to implement TTL; Annotation.timestamp or zipkin_spans.timestamp',
  `endpoint_ipv4` INT COMMENT 'Null when Binary/Annotation.endpoint is null',
  `endpoint_ipv6` BINARY(16) COMMENT 'Null when Binary/Annotation.endpoint is null, or no IPv6 address',
  `endpoint_port` SMALLINT COMMENT 'Null when Binary/Annotation.endpoint is null',
  `endpoint_service_name` VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Null when Binary/Annotation.endpoint is null'
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE zipkin_annotations ADD UNIQUE KEY(`trace_id_high`, `trace_id`, `span_id`, `a_key`, `a_timestamp`) COMMENT 'Ignore insert on duplicate';
```

With below query I am able to retrieve the rows from `zipkin_spans` with rows older than 5 days.

```
SELECT count(*) from zipkin_spans
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(zipkin_spans.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

But I would like to have the rows in `zipkin_annotations` with same traceIds. Please advice on this(with query).

Comment: You might want to look at "delete on cascade" foreign keys to see if they might be suitable for your tables. Could make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using sub-query, like this:

`SELECT * FROM zipkin_annotations
WHERE trace_id IN (SELECT trace_id from zipkin_spans
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(zipkin_spans.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))`

The inner query fetches all the *traceId*s from **zipkin_spans** with your required conditions, and the outer query fetches the records from **zipkin_annotations** only for those *traceId*s.

The above query will, of course, only select the rows, you can replace the `SELECT` with `DELETE` to delete the rows.

Another suggestion would be, while designing the schema, you could've used `Foreign key` for your purpose. There's an option called `Delete on cascade`, which would remove all the rows from **zipkin_annotations** with *traceId*s which are deleted from **zipkin_spans**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write two queries to delete it from two tables (If you don't have "Delete on cascade" for "Foreign Key").

To delete data from "zipkin_annotations" table :

```
DELETE ZA
FROM zipkin_spans AS ZS
INNER JOIN zipkin_annotations AS ZA ON ZS.trace_id = ZA.trace_id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(ZS.start_ts/1000000) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks @BhatiaAshish